# Elasticsearch : actions to take when bulk.rejected count is high

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, scaling, bulk, batching

If you see that the bulk.rejected count is high since bulk.queue size is much higher than bulk.active, what general actions do you take ? (assuming that you can scale your cluster easily)

e.g. using http://localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v

10.XX.XXX.XXX 10.XX.XXX.XXX 12 667845 208511 0 0 0 0 0 0

1. Scale out the master nodes (add more master machines, with same VM size)
2. Scale up the master nodes (keep same no. of machines, but increase the VM size to higher memory, higher CPU)
3. Scale out the data nodes
4. Scale up the data nodes
5. Scale out the client nodes
6. Scale up the client nodes
7. Decrease the no. of documents per batch (but it will increase the total requests to the cluster)

It could very well be multiple of the above, in which case if you could specify the order that would be great e.g. 4 -> 2 -> 6. Please feel free to suggest other steps that you may take.

Comment: How do you send your bulk queries to ES?

Comment: By directly using the bulk api (c# httpwebrequest), objects serialized to json, batch size 100.

Comment: How big (in KB/MB) are your documents, respectively, your 100-docs bulk query?

Comment: Doc size is reasonably small, max 2kb, 200kb total for one bulk request.

Comment: What is the rate at which you send those bulk request? and how many nodes do you have? Which ones are you sending the bulk queries to and what are their roles (data and/or master and/or client)?

Comment: Total 44 nodes. 6 masters, 4 clients, 34 data nodes. 2000qps.